# My quicksort algorithm is very slow so what can I do to make it faster?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

As you can see, this quicksort algorithm looks fine and it does work. The problem is it is very slow (according to a teacher), and a problem I'm facing is that this algorithm doesn't work for data size larger than 100000.

I think I am getting a stack overflow error
because of the recursive calls. When I make it print the sorted array of size 100k or laregr it does print the array and then a couple of seconds later I get an Error which refers to a couple of lines that casued it. In some cases while printing the array it stops and gives the same errors. So this got me wondering why the recursive calls keep on calling even after the *if statement (condition)* is fulfilled? Or did I misunderstand that, in that case what is causing it to give me an error after perfectly printing the sorted array?

All in all how do I make this algorithm faster
(according to a test class, this algorithm is not fast enough)? What is causing it to be slow that you guys can see here? I have made some changes myself but nothing that fixed it. And btw I have another algorithm class for random pivots so don't suggest that since this is specifically for fixed pivots.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class QuicksortFixedPivot{    
       
    public int partition(int [] array,  int first, int last){
        int pivot = array[last];
        int i = first - 1;
        
        for (int j = first; j < last; j++){
            if (array[j]<= pivot){
                i++;
                swap(array, i, j);
        
            }
        } 
        swap(array, i+1, last);
        return i+1;
    }
        
    private void quickSort(int [] array, int first, int last){
        if (first  < last){
            int pivot = partition(array, first, last);
            quickSort(array, first, pivot - 1);
            quickSort(array, pivot + 1, last);
        }
    }

    public void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
        }

    public void sort(int [] v){
        quickSort(v, 0, v.length - 1);
    }

}
```

Edit:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError.
Line 38 & 39 are the lines where quicksort method is recursively called.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add the rest of the code of your class and the test code as well.

Comment: *"then a couple of seconds later I get an Error which refers to a couple of lines that casued it"* - you may not understand what the error is telling you, but it is important information. You need to include the full error message in your question.

Comment: Hi, I don't have access to the TEST class it is failing, I can only send it in and then I get back a result whether it has passed or not. The only error I get is why it is failing and it says "Run Time error"

Comment: Your choice of pivot is bad in the case where the array is already sorted. And secondarily, if there can be duplicate elements in the input array, a 3-way partition (<pivot =pivot >pivot) is needed to avoid quadratic runtime.

Comment: You have said that there is an error which refers to some lines in your code. You have not said which lines. Furthermore even if you don't have access to your teacher's test code, there is nothing stopping you from testing the code yourself to identify where the error is occurring. You need to do this in order to provide the necessary information for other people to be able to answer your question.

Comment: For code for a learning assignment I would make the distinction between pivot element and pivot index more clear, e.g. by using more explicit variable names. This would not happen in a language like Rust that has usize for index position but I find it confusing that you use int for both your elements and your indices and then you have two variables named "pivot" where one contains an element and the other contains an index.

Comment: If you want to avoid a random pivot, choose the median of a[0], a[n/2] and a[n-1].

Comment: @kaya3 I was replying to Konrad Höffner. I have now edited my post and you can see the error at the end. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: Please post the full error, not just the first line. In this case it probably doesn't contain any more information but it is good to be sure. I suspect, as other commenters have suggested, that both the stack overflow error and the performance problems are caused by the choice of pivot.

Comment: Look at this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot.  It explains what happens when you make a poor choice of pivot, and what to do about it.  And in Java, the pathological behavior *manifests* as a stack overflow for a large enough input list.

Comment: "I don't have access to the TEST class it is failing" Well, then the first thing to do is write yourself a test suite!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle already sorted or reverse sorted data:

```java
    public int partition(int [] array,  int first, int last){
        int middle = (first+last)/2;    // use middle element for pivot
        swap(array, middle, last);
        int pivot = array[last];
        int i = first - 1;
        
        for (int j = first; j < last; j++){
            if (array[j]<= pivot){
                i++;
                swap(array, i, j);
        
            }
        } 
        swap(array, i+1, last);
        return i+1;
    }
```

Stack usage can be reduced to O(log2(n)) by recursing on smaller partition, looping for larger partition. Worst case time complexity is still O(n^2).

```java
     
    private void quickSort(int [] array, int first, int last){
        while (first  < last){
            int pivot = partition(array, first, last);
            if((pivot - first) <= (last - pivot){
                quickSort(array, first, pivot - 1);
                first = pivot + 1;
            } else {
                quickSort(array, pivot + 1, last);
                last = pivot - 1;
        }
    }
```

If there are a lot of duplicates, then Lomuto degrades towards worst case, while Hoare improves towards best case. Example code (the names will need to be changed):

```java
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public int partition(int[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if(lo >= hi)
            return;
        int p = a[lo+(hi-lo)/2];
        int i = lo-1;
        int j = hi+1;
        int t;
        while(true){                // partition
            while(a[++i] < p);
            while(a[--j] > p);
            if(i >= j)
                break;
            t     = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
        }
        return j;
    }

    private void quickSort(int [] array, int first, int last){
        while (first  < last){
            int split = partition(array, first, last);
            if((split - first) <= (last - split){
                quickSort(array, first, split);
                first = split + 1;
            } else {
                quickSort(array, split + 1, last);
                last = split;
        }
    }
```